# Error at executing Azure Pipeline for a .Net Desktop App - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm creating my first Pipeline to build a .NET Desktop application. I have added the needed task to my YML file but I'm getting the following error, regarding an assembly that may be missing or not found.

> Error Message: "The type or namespace name 'AxAcroPDFLibre' could not
> be found..."

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynmyl.png)

```
This is the complete code of my YML file:

# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:   vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:   solution: '**/*.sln'   buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'   buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2   inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1   inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2   inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
     
- task: CopyFiles@2       displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'       inputs:    
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'    
    Contents: '**/bin/**'    
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'       condition: succeededOrFailed()
       
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1       displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'       inputs:    
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'       condition: succeededOrFailed() I found this similar question here on StackOverflow, but I have checked my nugget package command and I have it in the build file.
```

At the end of the process, the job fails.

[Click here to see error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KHeY.png)

Right now that's all I've tried since I'm documenting myself on Azure DevOps Pipelines. If you have any recommendations I will appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your pipeline as such, it is failing to build your solution, so there is a missing dependency or package that is not present on your build agent.

Comment: Thank you @Sam Cogan. Is there a way to review that last part "...that is not present on your build agent". I'm using the free tier (Microsoft-hosted) provided by Azure DevOps to build my app. As you may imagine, locally on my computer I can build my app without any issue.